# how to rotate UI elements in unity only in one axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is question is very simple..

All I have is a new project with an **Image** inside a **Canvas**. The **Image** has a script attached to it called **Rotator**, and in the **Rotator** script all i'm doing is this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            float angle = Random.Range(0, 90);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
        }
```

However the result is that the **Image** always rotate on **X** and **Y** and I only want rotate around the **Z** axis, is there something that i'm missing here?

Comment: Try `Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, angle));`

Comment: @jiveturkey I don't know who upvoted your comment but this is just wrong ^^ Quaternion has 4 components x,y,z and w. If you don't know exactly what you are doing you would never access these individually and even less the way you do ;)

Comment: Is your UI in a Screen space overlay or does one of the parent objects have a different rotation?

Comment: I simply updated your Vector3 x and y values.

Comment: Apologies, `eulerAngles` not `rotation`.  As shown in the Answer.  Hope you would have figured that.

Answer (score 4):

**In single line:**

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, angle);
```

**Performance (for those concerned):**

`transform.eulerAngles` is a getter and internaly calls a function to calculate the angles so if we're using this multiple times it's a good practice to cache the result:

```
var eulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulerAngles.x, eulerAngles.y, angle);
```